# How to create new column with calculation of days between date in 2 other columns in DataFrame in Pandas Python?

Tags: python, pandas, string, date

I have DataFrame in Python Pandas like below:

```
col1                | col2
--------------------|--------------------
2020-01-10 19:45:49 | 2020-01-11 00:00:00
2020-01-24 20:14:33 | 2020-01-24 00:00:00
2020-01-24 11:43:15 | 2020-01-20 00:00:00
NaN                 | 2020-08-14 00:00:00
...                 | ...
```

- col1 is 'object' data type and could have 'NaN' values
- col2 is 'object' data type and does not have 'NaN' values

I need to create col3 which will present ow many days have passed since the date in col2 (col1 - col2):

- if in col1 is NaN in col3 also should be NaN
- if value in col2 is higher than in col1, value in col3 should be negative
- if value in col2 is lowe than in col1, value in col3 should be positive
- if the value in col2 and col1 is the same, value in col3 should be 0

So as a result I need something like below:

```
col1                | col2                | col3
--------------------|---------------------|----
2020-01-10 19:45:49 | 2020-01-11 00:00:00 | -1
2020-01-24 20:14:33 | 2020-01-24 00:00:00 | 0
2020-01-24 11:43:15 | 2020-01-20 00:00:00 | 4
NaN                 | 2020-08-14 00:00:00 | NaN
...                 | ...                 | ...
```

How can I do that in Python Pandas ?

Comment: What have you tried so far based on your own research, and what went wrong with your attempts? For example, [pd.to_datetime()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) would be a great place to start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```py
# ensure datetime:
df["col1"] = pd.to_datetime(df["col1"])
df["col2"] = pd.to_datetime(df["col2"])

df["col3"] = (df["col1"] - df["col2"]).dt.days

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                 col1       col2  col3
0 2020-01-10 19:45:49 2020-01-11  -1.0
1 2020-01-24 20:14:33 2020-01-24   0.0
2 2020-01-24 11:43:15 2020-01-20   4.0
3                 NaT 2020-08-14   NaN
```